# Cassandra 2.0.3 cqlsh Fail to start

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, cqlsh

I configured source code of Cassandra 2.0.3 in eclipse. JDK:jdk1.7.0_45 Win 7-32 bits, python 2.7.3 python but cqlsh just doesnt start.  Please help me what can be the possible problem?

Comment: how you are trying to start cassandra?
what errors are you getting?
give some more details.

Comment: And what is the error you got?

Comment: If I start cassandra from the bat file.everything runs perfectly fine including cqlsh and all cql commands..but when I run server from my configured source code (eclipse)..cli works fine but cqlsh throws error which is: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base10:'Unknown'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base10:'Unknown'

It happens when you run Cassandra from sources, and `version.properties` file is missing. Just execute `ant generate-eclipse-files` in the cassandra folder, that will generate the file.

Comment: While searching for solutions I got one which says to remove the line in cqlsh file, acquiring version i-e: self.cass_ver_tuple = tuple(map(int, vers['build'].split('-', 1)[0].split('.')[:3]))

It did the trick.. Whats you suggestion? Should I stick to it or revert back and generate version.properties file?

Comment: Either way will work. Though my personal preference would be using of a proper version file